# Finding installation path for GSL

Tags: linux, macos, terminal, installation, gsl

I need to install GSL for a package in R and so I did via macports using the following command:

`sudo port install gsl`

This seems to work successfully. What I need to know is how can I find the installation path for GSL. In order to install the package I need in R the article that was helping me with installation states I need to find GSL's installation path or as he puts it /path/to/gsl/installation/ . Anyone know where how I can find this path? I am using a Macbook Air with Mavericks installed

Comment: Try `which gsl`. macports usually installs to `/opt` then adds the path to your profile.

Comment: when i typed that into the terminal nothing happened

Comment: You can also try `locate gsl`, or `port installed` to find the package name.

Comment: locate gives locate gsl

WARNING: The locate database (/var/db/locate.database) does not exist.
To create the database, run the following command:

  sudo launchctl load -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.locate.plist

Please be aware that the database can take some time to generate; once
the database has been created, this message will no longer appear.

Comment: port installed gives:
The following ports are currently installed:
  gsl @1.16_2 (active)

Comment: Is there any other way to find this path? I guess the reason I am so confused is because I don't really understand what installation path means in this situation.

Answer (score 0):

MacPorts "installs" GSL headers into /opt/local/include, dylibs in /opt/local/lib, and at least a couple of binaries in /opt/local/bin. I'm not 100% sure, but R may be looking for the dylibs. If you want to list them:

```
$ cd /opt/local/lib
$ ls libgsl*
```

should show them to you.